# Three floating divs centered by the middle one

Tags: html, css

```
|-------------------A-------------------|
|                                       |
|        |---B--| |-C-| |------D----|   |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|---------------------------------------|
```

Hello,

I have a CSS question. My page has a header-area which has a image background (A) and on it there are three floating divs (B-D).
The background is wider than the actual width of the page, which is why I chose to place it as a div (in a lower z-index) for itself and not as a background-image to container div.

I made a JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lxgk44z/

For better demonstration I added background-colors.

My problem is that B and D have variable text-lengths and the page-width itself is also flexible (reacts gracefully to smaller screen sizes) but on the desktop I need C to be exactly horizontally centered with A. How can I achieve this?

For clarity sake: As for the smaller screen sizes (i.e. tablet or phone) I start to hide B and D, depending on what device is being used.

Thanks

Comment: Is this your solution? http://jsfiddle.net/0c928ho6/1/. To move to the right you need to use `margin-right`.

Comment: @Mardzis Everyone snipped and stole your answer!

Comment: actually not - theirs don't work as well as @Mardzis answer. There is only one problem with this solution: #C has "padding" at the top. If we can fist this and you make your comment into an answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: 4Farhan If it solves the problem, why not. @Capser Wait a minute!

Comment: Block C isn't in center in @Mardzis answer/

Comment: @Farhan: nobody stole nothing :-) I just didn't see this comment when I wrote my answer. Then I put upvote to the Mardzis comment and answer too. Answer should be posted as an answer, not a comment. Title at `add a comment` link says: '... Avoid answering questions in comments.' When I read question, often don't read comments because I don't looking for an asnwers in there.

Comment: @panther Ok :) Plagiarism is widespread on SO, so i thought so! Sorry!

Comment: @Farhan: okay :-) I leave my answer here, it's a little bit different from Mardzis solution, without additional `div`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is your solution:

[jsfiddle.net/0c928ho6/1](http://jsfiddle.net/0c928ho6/2/)

```css
#A { z-index: 1; height: 300px; min-width: 980px; max-width: 1280px; width: 100%; overflow:hidden; position: absolute; top: 0; display: block; margin: 0 auto; background-color: red; }

#BCD { text-align: center; z-index: 3; width: 980px; height: 250px; position: relative; display: block; margin: 0 auto; background-color: gray;}

#B { display: inline-block; height: 30px; padding: 10px; background-color: orange; }
#C { display: inline-block; width: 250px; height: 150px; margin: 0 10px; padding-top: 10px; background-color: green; }
#D { display: inline-block; height: 30px; padding: 10px; background-color: yellow; } 

.bdcouter {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 60px;}
```

```html
<div id="A">
    <div id="BCD">
        <div class="bdcouter">
            <div id="B">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
            <div id="C">[IMAGE]</div>
            <div id="D">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

You can `.bdouter` remove and add his CSS params to `#BCD`. But I think this is better.

Comment: I upvoted @panther, because his solution is a little more concise (didn't need the additional `div` but this was the first working solution.

Comment: I do have one question though: why the `margin-left: 60px;`?

Comment: This is only way how to target your div to center.

Comment: but what is it based on? Half of `#C`'s width would be i.e. 120px

Answer (score 3):

You can align parent to `center` and set to children `display: inline-block` instead of `float`.

```
#BCD {text-align: center}
#B, #C, #D {display: inline-block}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Lxgk44z/2/

Comment: Ok this is a little more concise to @mardiz answer, but there is still a space above the #C-div.

Comment: @Casper: Mardzis 'answered' into comment and I didn't see that. The space is caused by padding of `#B` element, which is 10px. Just add this negative top margin to `#C`, `#C {margin: -10px 10px 0;}`.

Answer (score -1):

I propose to

- add `float: left` to left block
- add `float: right` to right block
- add `display: inline-block` to center block
- add `text-align: center` to wrapper

http://jsfiddle.net/7xpg45rp/

And remark: Don't use `position absolute` in this way. The better way create bottom block which will be red. And use `position: absolute` for bottom block

Comment: This is not a solution, #B and #D need to hug #C

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lxgk44z/4/) It makes the C div will be always aligned in center, and the the other blocks are aligned to it according to your request.

```
 #A {
   z-index: 1;
   height: 300px;
   min-width: 980px;
   max-width: 1280px;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: red;
 }
 #BCD {
   z-index: 3;
   width: 980px;
   height: 250px;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: gray;
 }
 #B {
   position: absolute;
   right: 50%;
   margin-right: 135px;
   height: 30px;
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: orange;
 }
 #C {
   position: absolute;
   width: 250px;
   height: 150px;
   margin-left: -125px;
   left: 50%;
   background-color: green;
 }
 #D {
   position: absolute;
   height: 30px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: 135px;
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: yellow;
 }
```

Comment: This is not a solution, #B and #D need to hug #C

Comment: @Casper: Sorry, I've forgot to save the fiddle, but the CSS was right. Now the fiddle is also ok.